# C program Mac opening Safari Website

Tags: c, macos, terminal, safari

I try to write in C a program which lets me open the Safari browser/ a website such as google. I'm currently running my C code in Users/User/Documents....However, I think I need to access the Applications/Safari.app directory in Macintosh HD. But I have no idea how the code has to look like to change into that directory.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This opens the given URL in the current default browser.

```
system("open http://www.google.com");
```

If you are planning to do work with the website that you are trying to connect (as opposed to simply opening and displaying that webpage) then this approach would not be the best way to go about it.

Comment: Ahh thank you! Yeah, I would like to work with the website I connect to. Why would this way then not be the best way?

Comment: Simply because you have no programmatic handle to the page you just opened. If you need to do that use Ajax calls or curl calls.